# Как сгладить массив с помощью reduce?

Tags: javascript, массивы

```
let arr1 = [1, [2,[3,[4]]]];

let array = arr1.reduce( function (sum, elem) {
  return sum.concat(elem);
  }
);

console.log(array );
```

Ошибка:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: sum.concat is not a function
>     at index.html:635
>     at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
>     at index.html:634
>     (anonymous) @ index.html:635
>     (anonymous) @ index.html:634
> ```

В чем проблема?

Comment: В чем проблема подскажите пожалуйста(я новичок) P.S Заранее спасибо

Comment: сгладить? каким в конце должен быть ваш список?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, если я правильно понял вопрос, нужно посчитать сумму чисел во вложенных списках списка `arr1`, для начала мы преобразуем список списков в один список, в котором будут все данные и потом их сложим.

```js
let arr1 = [1, [2,[3,[4]]]];

//для глубокого упрощения используем рекурсивно reduce и concat
function flattenDeep(arr1) {
   return arr1.reduce((acc, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : acc.concat(val), []);
}
const array1 = flattenDeep(arr1);
console.log(array1); // => [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
result = array1.reduce(reducer);

console.log(result); // => 10
```

Источник:
1. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Нет нужно получить новый массив (однородный ) из подмассивов,но вы уже ответили на вопрос. СПС

Comment: Пожалуйста, можете тогда отредактировать вопрос, лучше всегда писать, что вы хотите получить в конце. Так же если вопрос полезен, то не стесняйтесь нажать верхний трегольник "ответ полезен" =)